# Permutations of a string --error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<char>::insert(std::string&)’

Tags: c++, string, list, set, permutation

I am not a professional `c++` programmer. I have tried to write a program to display all possible permutations of a given input string assuming if the string contains duplicate characters. This the code I have written so far:

**Latest update of my code (permutation.cpp):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

//factorial function 
int factorial(int n){
    if (n==0) return 1;
    else{
       return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
   srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed
   char* text;
   std::set<char> mySwapList;

   if ( argc < 1 )
   {
       cout << endl << "Please write a word in the following of the command line" << endl << endl;
       return 1;
   }
   else if ( argc != 2 ) // argc should be 2 for correct execution
   {  // We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name
       strcpy (text,argv[1]);
       cout<<endl<<"usage: "<< argv[0] <<" to compute all the permutations \n"<<endl;
       return 1;
   }   
   int ss=sizeof(text);
   int length = ss;
   int k=0;
   cout << "length of the word:"<<endl<< length<<endl;
   int total=factorial(length);
   while (k< total)
   { 
      char arr[ss];
      int index=0;
      stringstream ssin(text);
      while (ssin.good() && index<ss){
      ssin>>arr[index];
      ++index;
   }
      std::list<char> word(arr, arr+ss); 
      std::list<char> mylist;
      unsigned int j=0;
      while (j < length)
      {
           int n=word.size();
           int RandIndex = rand() % n;
           std::list<char>::iterator vi= word.begin();
           std::advance(vi,RandIndex);      
           std::list<char>::iterator iter= mylist.begin();
           mylist.insert(iter,*vi);
           word.remove(*vi);
           j++;
      }
      char str[ss];
      int ii=0;
      for (std::list<char>::iterator ix=mylist.begin(); ix!=mylist.end(); ++ix)
      {
          str[ii]=*ix;
          ii++;
      }
      string newWord = string(str);
      for (std::set<char>::iterator iss=mySwapList.begin(); iss!=mySwapList.end(); ++iss)
      {
      string w(1,*iss);
          if (newWord != w)
          {
             mySwapList.insert(newWord);
             k++;
      }
      }
   }
   //Loop for printing the list
   for(std::set<char>::iterator it = mySwapList.begin(); it != mySwapList.end(); ++it)
        cout << *it << " ";
    cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

I get a  a good deal of error messages when I compile the code, including:

**Updated errors:**

```
permutation.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
permutation.cpp:82:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<char>::insert(std::string&)’
              mySwapList.insert(newWord);
                                       ^
permutation.cpp:82:39: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/set:61:0,
                 from permutation.cpp:9:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:460:7: note: std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator, bool> std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = char; _Compare = std::less<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Key, std::_Identity<_Key>, _Compare, typename _Alloc::rebind<_Key>::other>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<char>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = char]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:460:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const char&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:497:7: note: std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = char; _Compare = std::less<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<char>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<char>; std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = char]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:497:7: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:517:2: note: template<class _InputIterator> void std::set<_Key, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = char; _Compare = std::less<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]
  insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
  ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_set.h:517:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
permutation.cpp:82:39: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
              mySwapList.insert(newWord);
```

I can not figure out why I got the above errors. Any suggestion?

Comment: And the question is?  The error messages tell you what is wrong, most of the time why, and where it is.

Comment: Notes: Calculate the factorial once and store it instead of recalculating it in the loop. Also `mySwapList` should rather be a set, than a list, so find is much faster. You can even just call `insert` w/o checking `find`. Also you probably won't get ALL possible permutations of the string. For that you'd better use real permutation instead of random generation (or use much more random "tries")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `vector` as a container for strings at the end of the code for `mySwapList` solves the problem of accepting `strings` as well as being easy to access each component of the `vector`. Here is the debugged and working version of the original question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <list>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using std::vector;

//factorial function 
int factorial(int n){
    if (n==0) return 1;
    else{
       return n*factorial(n-1);
    }
}


int main () {
   srand ( time(NULL) ); //initialize the random seed
   std::string text;
   vector<std::string> mySwapList;
   std::ostream_iterator<char> output(cout," ");
   cout << endl << "Please write a word in the following of the command line" << endl << endl;
   cin >>text;   
   int ss=text.size();
   int k=0;
   cout << "length of the word:" << endl << ss<<endl<<"input value:\n" <<text<< endl;
   int total=factorial(ss);
   cout << "The number of final permutations :\n"<<total<<endl;

   while (k< total)
   { 
      char arr[ss];
      int index=0;
      stringstream ssin(text);
      while (ssin.good() && index<ss){
    ssin>>arr[index];
    ++index;
      }
      std::list<char> word;
      //insert items from arr into word list
      word.insert(word.begin(),arr, arr+ss);
      //A tool to print lists

      cout<<"word contains:\n "<<endl;
      std::copy(word.begin(),word.end(),output);
      cout << endl;
      std::list<char> mylist;
      unsigned int j=0;
      while (j < ss)
      {
    int n=word.size();
    int RandIndex = rand() % n;
    std::list<char>::iterator vi= word.begin();
    std::advance(vi,RandIndex);
    word.erase(vi);

    std::list<char>::iterator iter= mylist.begin();
    mylist.insert(iter,*vi);
    j++;
      }
      cout << "constructed permuted word:"<<endl;
      std::copy(mylist.begin(),mylist.end(),output);
      cout << endl;
      char str[ss];
      str[ss]='\0';
      int ii=0;
      for (std::list<char>::iterator ix=mylist.begin(); ix!=mylist.end(); ++ix)
      {
      str[ii]=*ix;
          ii++;
      }
      string newWord = string(str);
      cout << "New Word :"<< endl << newWord <<" size of string:\n"<< (sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str)) << endl;

      if (k==0)
      {
         mySwapList.push_back(newWord);
         k++;

      }
      else     
      {
    int flag=0;
        for (int i=0;i<mySwapList.size();i++)
        {
          if (mySwapList[i]==newWord)
         flag=1;
        }
        if (flag!=1)
    {
         mySwapList.push_back(newWord);
         k++;    
    }
      }  
   }
   //Loop for printing the vector mySwapList
   for(unsigned int i=0; i<mySwapList.size();i++)
      cout << mySwapList[i] << " ";
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the question title you want to convert `string` to `list`.
You can't do it directly but you can use `string` iterator:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string strTest = "hello!";
    std::list<char> list(strTest.begin(), strTest.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: But based on your code you don't need `list` at all. You can use `std::string` everywhere. It has `insert` and `[]` stuff. It is almost the same as `vector<char>` but with additional functionality.

Comment: as you pointed out I want to get a word from a command line and split it to a list of letters plus I would like to add and remove items from this list that is again caused error messages.

Comment: I've edit my answer. All you need is `std::string`. It is organized as `array` of `char`. `List` is actually is linked list (each item has pointer to `prev` and `next`). So that structure does not support random access.

Comment: `size_t length = text.length() + sizeof('\0');` Is incorrect: it is summing `count` of chars in the string and `memory size` of one `char`. So usually `str.length()` is what people need.

Comment: @ DmitriyZapevalov I debugged my code as much as I could and I updated the final version. I don't know how I can add a `string` to a `set` and it caused getting error messages.

Comment: I've tried to rewrite your code. But it's complitly has no meaning. First replace `std::set<char>` and `std::list<char>` and `char str[ss]` to `std::string`. Then don't use `sizeof`. Then replace 'remove' to `erase`. Then try to avoid work with `iterators` - use `indices` instead. Also I recommend to write and debug code piece by piece. You have to check each piece ar runtime - so code has to be compileble.

Answer (score 0):

You used undefined class members.
Try `strcpy_s()` to `char*` arrays.